# Cannot allocate memory error

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using wordpress on my website http://cbsse.co.in

but when I am trying to open the page then it is giving a blank page. When I see its error log then it says

```
[Wed Mar 09 14:38:18.388826 2016] [:error] [pid 855975] (12)Cannot allocate memory: [client 123.108.201.27:2188] couldn't create child process: /opt/suphp/sbin/suphp for /home/cbssecoin/public_html/index.php, referer: http://cbsse.co.in/wp-admin/customize.php?return=%2Fwp-admin%2Ftheme-editor.php
[Wed Mar 09 14:38:18.380300 2016] [:error] [pid 855975] (12)Cannot allocate memory: [client 123.108.201.27:2188] couldn't create child process: /opt/suphp/sbin/suphp for /home/cbssecoin/public_html/wp-admin/load-scripts.php, referer: http://cbsse.co.in/wp-admin/customize.php?return=%2Fwp-admin%2Ftheme-editor.php
[Wed Mar 09 14:28:43.696857 2016] [:error] [pid 858841] (12)Cannot allocate memory: [client 123.108.201.27:1836] couldn't create child process: /opt/suphp/sbin/suphp for /home/cbssecoin/public_html/index.php, referer: http://cbsse.co.in/h-s-12-th-for-pure-science/
[Wed Mar 09 13:19:50.195968 2016] [:error] [pid 785653] (12)Cannot allocate memory: [client 123.108.201.27:3258] couldn't create child process: /opt/suphp/sbin/suphp for /home/cbssecoin/public_html/index.php, referer: http://cbsse.co.in/results/
```

I am not getting why these error are?

I have edited wp-config also

```
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );
```

Please help how I can be out of the problem

Comment: I think it is related to the server issue. If you have the server access and if it is linux server then execute top command you will see all the process with memory consumption figure for each process..

Answer (score 0):

When I open the link you have given, I'm getting "500: Internal Server Error".

So Please check if you have any syntax error in the config file.

Answer (score 0):

As @AlankarMore told you in the comments it's a server problem. If you have access to httpd.conf look for `RLimitMEM`. If it has a value set just comment the whole line. Also you can try altering `memory_limit` in php.ini. Altering the memory limit in `wp-config.php` is not always considered by server.

If this doesn't help you try contaction your server support, they'll solve it for you.